# I need some help designing an array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

For my homework, we've been tasked with creating:

`Person` class with variables `firstName, lastName, streetAddress, zipCode` and `phone`.

`CollegeEmployee` extends `Person` and adds `ssn, salary,` and `deptName`.

`Faculty` extends `CollegeEmployee` by adding a boolean `tenure`.

Last but not least, `Student` extends `person` by adding `GPA` and `major`.

Everything looks good displaying to screen, and I'm moving on to the next part of the assignment which is to create 14 records (7 students, 4 employees and 3 faculty) in an array.

3 different classes, with multiple data types, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to populate an array with this. This is the first array I've created that's not been completely integer. The Java Tutorials didn't give me anything, and while [Java: Generic Static Multidimensional Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924473/java-generic-static-multidimensional-arrays) has some great information, it's a little more than I can wrap my head around right now.

I'd initially thought of creating `array[14][10]` -- fourteen variables each for ten objects -- but I can't mix data types. That's where I got lost.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to design this array and be able to display the values from it afterward?

Any hints and suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: You need to revisit OOP basics. All of your objects are `Person`s

Comment: A faculty **is-a** college employee? Not in reality ;)

Comment: @Andreas_D - I think you need to look up "faculty". I don't think people off the street walk in and teach classes ;)

Comment: OK: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/faculty - to my and wiktionaries understanding, a faculty is a staff or a division. A person (a college employee) can be *a member* of a faculty. But the meaning may have changed over the years ;)

Comment: Fair enough, but in the context he used it (with `tenure`) I think it was apparent as to what he was getting at ;) Perhaps `FacultyMember` for the classname instead. In my head when I think of "Faculty" I think of a teacher rather than the group, so I could easily make the same leap in naming if I didn't think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also create a `Person[]` array, just as you would an `int[]` array. e.g.

```
Person[] people = new Person[14]
```

You can then add people to the Array like this:

```
people[0] = new Student();
people[1] = new CollegeEmployee();
people[2] = new Faculty();
```

If you want to check what type of person is in each index you will want to use `instanceof`. Try looking [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/TheinstanceofKeyword.htm) for more help

One example of using `instanceof` is:

```
if(people[0] instanceof Student){
    System.out.println("This person is a student");
}
```

Or try using generics.

You could create an `ArrayList<Person>` and can then add any type of person to this ArrayList.

e.g.

```
ArrayList<Person> peopleList = new ArrayList<Person>();
//People can be added like this
peopleList.add(new Student());
peopleList.add(new CollegeEmployee();)
```

Again you are able to use `instanceof` to check which type of person is in each index!

Also if you never write

```
Person person1 = new Person();
```

In your code then consider making your class abstract.

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, no need to get fancy with multi-dimensional arrays.

1)  Create an array that takes `Person` instances.

`Person [] myPeeps = new Person[14];`

2)  Create a `print` method on `Person`, which subclasses override to print the relevant info.

Because your array expects `Person` instances, you can put instances of any subclasses of `Person`, because subclasses always have an **is-a** relationship with their superclass.

Because Person has a `print` method, you can call `print` on anything you pull out of the array.  Subclasses provide their own implementations so they can print their relevant data.  That way, you don't really care about which subclass any particular instance is; the correct `print` implementation for the instance is invoked at runtime.

Comment: +1 for `print` method instead of overriding `toString`, which should be used for debugging purposes only.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a multidimensional array. You can make an array of Person objects.

```
Person[] people = new Person[14];
people[0] = new Student();
people[1] = new Employee();
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

To start:

Person[] myArray = new Person[14];

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially why object oriented programming is so wonderful. If you'll notice, all `Faculty`, `CollegeEmployee`, and `Student` are a subset of type `Person`. Because of this, you can have them all contained in the same dataset if it is declared as type `Person`.

```
Person[] array = new Person[14];
```

You can add all of your objects to that array; however, be careful. When you go to use the elements of the array Java now only knows that each has the methods that a `Person` does - so therefore you can only make use of `firstName`, `lastName`, `streetAddress`, `zipCode`, and `phone` from these elements unless you cast the objects after they are retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

Since they are all of type `Person`, why not use a `Person` array?

```
Person [] people = new Person[14];
```

You can safely add all types of `Person` to this array, however you can only treat them as `Person` (without casting). To have each subclass output customized details, and add this method in `Person`

```
class Person {
    void print() {
        // default Person printing
    }
}
```

and override this method in each subclass to print its member variables:

```
class Student extends Person {
    void print() { // <-- note same method signature!
       // print "I'm a Student", GPA, major
    }        
}
```

and when the array is populated:

```
for (Person p : people) {
    p.print(); // delegates to print method associated with the underlying type
}
```

- Check out the [inheritance tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Answer (score 0):

The class `Person` is a common superclass to all the types of the objects you want to store in the array.  You can create the array based on that common supertype.  Then you can access methods that are defined in that tpe on all elements of the array, regardless of the actual type -- the behavior is as defined in the actual type (look up inheritance for java if this is not clear).

If you need specific behavior based on the actual type, you need to cast the array element to the concrete type (you can determine it using `instanceof`, for example)